# Null analyzer in eclipse shows false positive

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring

I have the following code

```
    public static @NonNull String getSubstitutedString(String currentPath, String value, Matcher matcher)
    {
      int prevEnd = 0;
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(currentPath.length());
      do {
        result.append(currentPath.substring(prevEnd, matcher.start()));
        prevEnd = matcher.end();
        if (isNested(result)) {
          result.append(currentPath.substring(matcher.start(), prevEnd));
        }
        else {
          result.append(value);
        }
      }
      while (matcher.find());
      return result.append(currentPath.substring(prevEnd)).toString();
    }
  }
```

Eclipse warns me that the return statement is:
`Null type safety: The expression of type 'String' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull String'`

How can I convince Eclipse that `toString` will never return `null`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `@NonNull` annotation is **not** in JDK. Which library are you importing the annotation from?

Comment: Since the system library is not shipped with null annotations, either by `@SuppressWarnings("null") @NonNull String resultString =...; return resultString;` or by using external null annotations for the system library, e.g. https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments

Comment: I'm aware it's not in the JDK. I think the null annotations are losing 50% of their value, if non of the jdk is assumes as NonNull by default. To suppress the warnings all the time is cumbersome.
But if that's how it is.